# Как можно реализовать выбор вариантов с помощью блоков с картинками?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Есть машазин на  **wordpress(woocommerce)**

Подскажите, как можно реализовать подобные поля с выбором вариантов?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<h2>Способ оплаты</h2>
<select>
  <option>Налтчный расчет</option>
  <option>Онлайн оплата банковской картой</option>
</select>
```

Comment: А зачем `select`?

Comment: @Дмытрык ну можно и `radio button`, но только как? иммитировать клик?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select тут вообще не подходит, к нему не реально нужные стили применить. Нужно делать через radio и label. Применить нужные стили к label не сложно.

Создаем несколько radio, к каждому radio создаем привязанный label. Radio нужно скрыть с помощью display: none.
Далее прикол в том, что по клику на label, переключается и связанный с label-ом radio button.
Потом в js отслеживаешь какой radio button нажат. 
Вот накидал на codepen примерно как можно сделать, без js. Получить значение радио на js не сложно будет дальше.
https://codepen.io/IGrock88/pen/vVVBLQ.

```
 <div>
  <input id='cash' type="radio" class='radio' name='buy-type'>
  <label for="cash" class='label'>Наличный расчёт</label>
  <input id='cart' type="radio" class='radio' name='buy-type'>
  <label for="cart" class='label'>Оплата картой</label>
</div>

div{
  display: flex;

}

.radio{
  display: none;
}

.label{
  display: block;
  background-color: lightgray;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.radio:checked+.label{
  background-color: gray;
}
```

Comment: есть сложность когда `input` внутри у `label` как у меня счас во взятом коде

Comment: причем `input` принимает свойство `checked` только уже после нажатия кнопки `button`

Comment: в продолжение темы https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/896936/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%83-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2