# Не получается радиокнопками менять цвета у блоков

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Есть 2 блока. При переключении `ìnput[type="radio"]` должен меняться цвет у их лейблов. Казалось бы банальнейшая задача, но бьюсь над ней и не выходит.( 
Для меня новостью было узнать, что при выборе активной кнопки не загорается атрибут `checked`, думал сразу через него.

Установить `prop("checked", true)` да, можно, но что это даст?

**Код**

```js
$('input[name="order_time"]').change(function() {
  $this = $(this).parent("label");
  if ($this.hasClass("label-active")) {
    $('#order_time_field label').each(function() {
      if ($(this).hasClass("label-active")) {
        $(this).removeClass('label-active');
      }
    });

    $this.addClass("label-active");
  } else {
    $this.addClass("label-active");
  }
});
```

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 210px;
  height: 99px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: 'Circe';
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 0.45px;
}

label.label-active {
  background-color: #e4e4e4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-priority="20" class="form-row form-row-wide" id="order_time_field">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Время доставки</legend><label class="label-active"><input type="radio" name="order_time" value="Ближайшее"> Ближайшее</label><label class=""><input type="radio" name="order_time" value="К определенному времени"> К определенному времени</label></fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: #order_time_field - у тебя нет ни одного элемента, подходящего этому селектору

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Даже и не знаю как тут что комментировать:

```js
let $inputs = $('input[type=radio]');
let className = 'label-active';

$inputs.change(function(ev){
  $inputs.closest('label').removeClass(className);
  $(this).closest('label').addClass(className)
})
```

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 210px;
  height: 99px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: 'Circe';
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 0.45px;
}

label.label-active {
  background-color: #e4e4e4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-priority="20" class="form-row form-row-wide" id="order_time_field">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Время доставки</legend>
    <label class="label-active">
      <input type="radio" name="order_time" value="Ближайшее"> Ближайшее</label>
    <label class="">
      <input type="radio" name="order_time" value="К определенному времени">
      К определенному времени</label>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо! А глобально проблема где у меня была? что делал не так?

Answer (score 2):

Я не увидел вопроса в вопросе, но попробую предложить решение).

Я бы написал так:

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[name="order_time"]', ((e) => {   
    $('#order_time_field').find('.label-active').removeClass('label-active');
    $(e.currenttarget).closest("label").addClass('label-active');
});
```

Comment: спасибо! А глобально проблема где у меня была? что делал не так?